# Convergence of a "simple" stochastic algorithm

Tags: convergence-divergence, stochastic-processes, stochastic-analysis, probability-limit-theorems

In this question, we will consider the convergence of an algorithm as follows.

Let $f(x) = \frac{1}{2}x^2$ be our objective function. We define a so-called forcing function $\rho(\alpha) = \frac{1}{2}\alpha^2$. Then given an initial point $x_0$ and initial step size $\alpha_0$, we define the following iteration:

1. generate a random number $d_k$ with probability $\mathbb{P}(d_k = 1) = \mathbb{P}(d_k = -1) = \frac{1}{2}$;
2. if $f(x_k+\alpha_k d_k)<f(x_k)-\rho (\alpha_k)$ (i.e. $\alpha_{k}<-d_kx_k$), then $x_{k+1} = x_k+\alpha_k d_k$ and $\alpha_{k+1} = 2\alpha_k$; if not, $x_{k+1} = x_{k}$ and $\alpha_{k+1} = \frac{1}{2}\alpha_k$.

I am curious that if this algorithm has the following convergence property:
$$
\mathbb{P}\left( \lim_{k\to\infty}|x_k| = 0 \right) = 1.
$$

There is an important observation. Here the step size $\alpha_k$ will converge to 0 with probability 1. This is due to the forcing function $\rho(\alpha)$, if not, we can show that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \rho(\alpha_k)=\infty$ which contradicts that $f(x)$ has a lower bound.

I find this well-defined "simple" question actually not easy to analyze. I believe it is convergent. I tried to show this by Borel-Cantelli Lemma but failed.

I think the step size $a_k$ can be regarded as a stochastic process:
$$a_k = a_0 2^{\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} Y_i},\quad k\ge 1$$
where $Y_i = 2*\mathbf{1}_{\{\alpha_{k}<-d_kx_k\}}-1$.
Then we may consider $S_k = \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} Y_i$, however, it is far from a random walk.
Any idea will help. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes if I am not wrong. The idea is that $\alpha_k$ can't be always very small and will, eventually, have the same order as $x_k$, thus $x_{k + 1} = x_k + d_k\alpha_k$ will be significantely closer to $0$ than $x_k$ (at least twice closer).

First of all, I assume you step is positive. I also assume $x_0 \neq 0$, else the problem is trivial. In this case, for each $k$, we have $\alpha_k < -d_kx_k$, then $d_kx_k < 0$ so the sign of $d_k$ is opposite to the sign of $x_k$, which implies that $x_{k + 1} = x_k + d_k\alpha_k = d_k(\alpha_k + d_kx_k)$ also has an opposite sign to $d_k$ (because $\alpha_k + d_kx_k < 0$). We deduce that $(x_k)$ has a constant sign. Without loss of generality, assume that $x_0 > 0$, thus for all $k$, $x_k > 0$ and $(x_k)$ clearly decreases.

Let us write for all $k$, $\alpha_k = \alpha_02^{m_k}$ where $m_k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $m_0 = 0$. Notice that at each step $k$, $\alpha_k < -d_kx_k$ is equivalent to $d_k = -1$ and $\alpha_k < x_k$ i.e. $m_k < \log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}\right)$, which is equivalent to $m_k \leqslant \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}\right)\right\rceil - 1$ since $m_k$ is an integer.

Now, consider the decreasing sequence of integers $a_k = \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}\right)\right\rceil - 1$. Let for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, $I_k = \{q \geqslant k|a_q = a_k\}$. Each $I_k$ is clearly an integers interval. While $q \in I_k$, we have,
$$
m_{k + 1} = \left\{
\begin{array}{l}
m_k + 1 \textrm{ if } d_k = -1 \textrm{ and } m_k \leqslant a_k,\\
m_k - 1 \textrm{ else}.
\end{array}
\right.
$$
We recognise a random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ with a stop line at $a_k$ (which is fixed while we remain in $I_k$). Notice that it is possible that $m_{k + 1} > a_k$ but in this case, the $m_q$ will decrease until $m_q = a_k$.

This walk is reccurent in $\mathbb{Z} \cap ]-\infty,a_k]$ so we will have $m_q = a_k$ infinitely many times unless $I_k$ is bounded. And infinitely many times, when $m_q = a_k$, we will have $d_q = -1$. Let $q \geqslant k$ be an integer such that $m_q = a_k$ and $d_q = -1$.

In this case,
\begin{align*}
x_{q + 1} & = x_q - \alpha_q\\
& = x_q - \alpha_02^{a_k}\\
& = \alpha_0\left(\frac{x_q}{\alpha_0} - 2^{a_k}\right).
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
a_{q + 1} & = \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_{q + 1}}{\alpha_0}\right)\right\rceil - 1\\
& = \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_q}{\alpha_0} - 2^{a_k}\right)\right\rceil - 1\\
& \leqslant \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0} - 2^{a_k}\right)\right\rceil - 1.
\end{align*}
And we have $a_k = \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}\right)\right\rceil - 1 \geqslant \log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}\right) - 1$ so $2^{a_k + 1} \geqslant \frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}$, which implies $\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0} - 2^{a_k} \leqslant 2^{a_k}$. We deduce that $\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0} - 2^{a_k}\right) \leqslant a_k$ thus $a_{q + 1} \leqslant \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0} - 2^{a_k}\right)\right\rceil - 1 \leqslant a_k - 1$.

By definition, it means that $q + 1 \notin I_k$. Such a $q$ exists with probability $1$ for all $k$ hence each $I_k$ is bounded with probability $1$. It means that $a_k \rightarrow -\infty$, so $x_k \rightarrow 0$ with probability $1$.

Comment: Very beautiful proof! I am so happy to see you analyze the behavior of such an interval $I_k$ because before I did almost the same proof as yours (create a random walk with one-side reflecting boundary) except finding a way to show the inteval for the random walk is bounded with probability 1. So much thanks!

Comment: But I found a small problem after I recheck this. By the definition of $I_k$, we can see that the value of $a_q$ will not change, which implies that $x_q$ in this interval will not move, i.e., $m_q=m_{q-1}-1$ for all $q\in I_k$ unless the last $q$ in this interval. And this random walk in this interval may not achieve $m_q = a_k$ since once $m_q=m_{q+1}+1$ then $a_q$ will change and we will go out the interval $I_k$.

Comment: To solve this problem, I have two ideas. First is that, we still try to show that all of  the intervals $I_k$ you construct are bounded with probability 1. Second is to construct a new type interval between the arrival times $m_k=a_k$.

Comment: $a_q$ doesn't change when you stay in an $I_k$ but it doesn't mean that $x_q$ doesn't change. This is due to the fact that you take the ceil of your log. Actually, $q \in I_k$ means that $a_q = \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_q}{\alpha_0}\right)\right\rceil = \left\lceil\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}\right)\right\rceil = a_k$ so by definition there exists an integer $N$ such that $N < \log_2\left(\frac{x_q}{\alpha_0}\right),\log_2\left(\frac{x_k}{\alpha_0}\right) \leqslant N + 1$, which means that $(x_q)$ stays in the interval $]\alpha_02^N,\alpha_02^{N + 1}]$ but it can change.

Comment: And once you know that each $I_k$ is bounded, you get that $a_k \rightarrow -\infty$ (or else $(a_k)$ would be stationnary which contradicts the unboundedeness of the $I_k$), thus $x_k \leqslant \alpha_02^{a_k} \rightarrow 0$.

Comment: Thanks for your patient explanation. Now I am wondering whether this kind of convergence can be extended from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, that is, to change $f(x) = x^2/2$ and $\mathbb{P}(d_k = 1) = \mathbb{P}(d_k = -1) = 1/2$ to $f(x) = x^\top x/2$ and $d_k \sim \operatorname{Unif}(\mathbf{S}^{n-1})$ respectively, where $\operatorname{Unif}(\mathbf{S}^{n-1})$ means uniform distribution on the unit sphere in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: It seems much harder to solve but intuitively, I would say that yes for $n = 2$ and no for $n \geqslant 3$ because the key argument in the proof is the fact that the random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$ is reccurent, and the random walk in $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is recurrent if and only if $n \leqslant 2$. However, it is only a vague intuition, I don't know what happens if you take a walk in $\mathbb{R}^n$ where each step is a uniform law in the sphere.

Comment: Great intuition! I also think so. Let me try and show results here if there is any progress. Thank you.